# Proportional Edit

Tags: interface

I do not have a mouse. I'm the user of a Mac Book Pro Touch ID I mean have to keep with a touchpad so how am I going to select the proportional edit as in a circle.

Grab with <kbd>G</kbd> and then?

Comment: Hi. I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but please try and make the title more specific to what you are asking and not just the general topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the pop-up menu.
Check *Proportional Editing* and adjust the slider.

While this way doesn't show a circle, you can adjust it more precisely.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is the shortcut key for proportional editing "O" this will select the it and now you can edit in any manner, press it again to deactivate, to increase or decrease size you may have to enable a graphic tablet.

Answer (score 0):

- Enter Edit Mode;
- Turn on *Proportional Editing*;
- Select a desired point;
- Grab with  <kbd>G</kbd>;
- Click the selected point again, and you will see a pop-up menu;
- Set the proportional size **between the major radius and minor radius** of the object.